# Cassandra - Same partition key in different tables - when it is right?

Tags: cassandra, partition, scylla

I modeled my Cassandra in a way that i have couple of tables with the same partition key - Uuid.

Each table has it's partition key and others column representing data for specific query i would like to ask.

For example - 1 table have Uuid and column regarding it's status (no other clustering keys in this table) and table 2 will contain the same Uuid (Also without clustering keys) but with different columns representing the data for this Uuid.

Is it the right modeling? Is it wrong to duplicate the same partition key around tables in order to group each table to hold relevant column for specific use case? or it preferred to use only 1 table and query them and taking the relevant data for the specific use case in the code?

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing **wrong** with this modeling. Whether it is better, or worse, than the obvious alternative of having just one table with both pieces of data, depends on your workload:
For example, if you commonly need to read *both* status and data columns of the same uuid, then these reads will be more efficient if both things are in the same table, which only needs to be looked up once. If you always read just one but not both, then reads will be more efficient from separate tables. Also, if this workload is not read-mostly but rather write-mostly, then writing to just one table instead of two will be more efficient.

Comment: Actually, the status table is getting read a lots of times and updated once in a while and the data reads seldom. Is it common case that we will create couple of tables contain the same partition key but each table will contain others column answering specific question? Or most of the time we will create large table and query different SELECT query returning the desired data?

Comment: Can you provide some reference to documents supporting your answer?

Comment: I don't know what kind of reference you're looking for, Google may help you better than I can. But one good starting point is https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling. It mentions rules like "duplication of data is a fact of life with Cassandra. Don't be afraid of it." but "When you issue a read query, you want to read rows from as few partitions as possible.", but please read the whole thing. Of course as you noticed the "rules" conflict, so you need to pick the one most relevant to your specific use case.